# Get unobtrusive validation attribute in html helper extensions from just a class name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

Is it possible to get unobtrusive validation attributes in html helper extensions method from just a class name.

I have a class which has data annotations in place.

```
public class UserDetails
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string Firstname{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Second Name")]
    public string SecondName{ get; set; }      
}
```

My aim is to get all the unobtrusive validation attributes by just using the "UserDetails" class name.

Any suggestion?